# How to create Theano shared variables on GPU?

Tags: python, linux, gpu, theano

I am using Theano to train my model on a Linux machine. The code runs good at CPU, but has an error when I switched back to GPU in the same machine: `AttributeError: 'TensorVariable' object has no attribute 'get_value'`.

I find one of the parameter that constructed from a `numpy` array is not a shared variable, but is instead a normal `TensorVariable` if I run it on GPU. But there is no such issue in CPU. I ran to the same problem on CPU before, I fixed it by casting the numpy array to the same float type of `theano.config.floatX`. But I don't know how to fix this problem.

**Configuration**

The configuration file `~/.theanorc` looks like this:

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = cuda
```

I am using Python3 and the GPU environment for Theano is already set up.

**Code**

The `theano.shared` function is not creating a GPU array shared variable but a normal tensor variable. The code I use is:

```
self.one_matrix = theano.shared(
    np.array(one_matrix,
             dtype=theano.config.floatX),
    name="OneMatrix") \
    .astype(theano.config.floatX)
```

**Output**

On GPU:

type(self.one_matrix): `<class 'theano.tensor.var.TensorVariable'>`

type(one_matrix): `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

one_matrix.dtype: `float32`

I am wondering how I can create a shared variable from numpy array. Is anything I need to do to make this code works on GPU as well? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply modify my code as this makes it work, though I am not sure why.

```
self.one_matrix = theano.shared(
     one_matrix,
     name="OneMatrix") \
    .astype(theano.config.floatX)
```